# How to create a matrix using this data

Tags: r

I have encountered a problem while I was doing my homework/assignment and I would appreciated your expertise if anyone is willing to help :)

I have a file called raceIDs (which looks like this):

```
> raceIDs
[1] "GER" "SUI" "NZ2" "US1" "US2" "POR" "FRA" "AUS" "NZ1" "SWE"
```

I have also created a function called:

```
getTimes()
```

For example, if I enter:

```
> getTimes("GER")
[1] "11:10:02" "11:35:05"  #Shows the starting and finishing times
```

What I need to do here is to create a matrix showing the starting and ending times for all the countries.

For example, I should be getting a matrix of the following result:

```
> raceTimes
    start        finish
GER "11:10:02"   "11:35:05"
SUI "11:10:02"   "11:35:22"
#and so on....
```

**My attempt:**

```
> GER <- getTimes("GER")
> SUI <- getTimes("SUI")
> NZ2 <- getTimes("NZ2")
> US1 <- getTimes("US1")
> US2 <- getTimes("US2")
> POR <- getTimes("POR")
> FRA <- getTimes("FRA")
> AUS <- getTimes("AUS")
> NZ1 <- getTimes("NZ1")
> SWE <- getTimes("SWE")

> allTimes<-c(GER, SUI, NZ2, US1, US2, POR, FRA, AUS, NZ1, SWE)
> raceTimes <- matrix(allTimes, ncol=2)
> rownames(raceTimes) <- paste(raceIDs)
> colnames(raceTimes) <- c("start", "finish")

> raceTimes
    start      finish    
GER "11:10:02" "11:10:02"
SUI "11:35:05" "11:34:31"
NZ2 "11:10:02" "11:10:02"
US1 "11:35:22" "11:34:45"
US2 "11:10:02" "11:10:03"
POR "11:34:12" "11:36:48"
FRA "11:10:01" "11:10:01"
AUS "11:33:29" "11:35:16"
NZ1 "11:10:01" "11:10:03"
SWE "11:36:05" "11:35:08"
```

As you can see above, my matrix is not correct. For example, the finish result for "GER" ("11:35:05") is showing as the start time for "SUI".

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common mistake: creating a matrix or array out of a vector fills in column-major order, as the [introduction manual states](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Arrays)::

> The values in the data vector give the values in the array in the same
>   order as they would occur in FORTRAN, that is “column major order,”
>   with the first subscript moving fastest and the last subscript
>   slowest.

This can be observed by

```
matrix(1:4, ncol = 2)

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
```

The most immediate fix is to add `byrow = TRUE` to your `matrix` call.

```
matrix(1:4, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    3    4

raceTimes <- matrix(allTimes, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
```

A better idea would be to use `rbind` upstream to do the joining without needing to string together a vector:

```
raceTimes <- rbind(GER, SUI, NZ2, US1, US2, POR, FRA, AUS, NZ1, SWE)
```

A better idea would be to use looping and `sapply` instead of typing out `getTimes` for each element in `raceID`:

```
raceTimes <- sapply(raceID, getTimes)
raceTimes <- t(raceTimes)
```